# FBX SDK - convert all content of fbx file to text

Tags: c++, autodesk, fbx

I'm trying to learn what is within an FBX file (all of the content), but I can't see all of them in program like Blender or Maya because my knowledge about FBX is not enough, I can't tell if there is some hidden settings in the FBX files.

Actually, I'm doing this because:

1. I'm curious by nature and want to see what inside.
2. I'm having problem importing FBX into a game engine so that I want to compare the good FBX vs bad FBX so I can figure out the culprit.

I want to convert these FBX files to text so that I can read them with human eyes. I've checked the FBX SDK samples but I still can't find my answer. But I guess this thing has been done in some programs (for example- Blender, when Blender tries to read an FBX file, it has to read all the content of FBX files to work with it, but I'm lost in the source code of Blender for now).

Comment: I'm not sure about Blender or Maya, but in 3dsmax you can choose binary or textual format for FBX. Also, you always can read FBX with SDK and dump content in any representation you want.

Comment: Thank Michael :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code sample named "[ImportScene](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2020/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_import_scene_2main_8cxx_example_html)" in the fbx sdk does exactly what you want. It's a command line program that takes a fbx file path as an input argument and outputs in text as much as possible information related to the file (this is a code sample not an official text representation, I don't think such thing exists) You will have to download the sdk and compile the code sample for yourself.

Alternatively the sample code "[SceneTreeView](https://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_3DE46B9A_A7EE_403E_866B_427B800F9F9D_htm)" displays as a graphical tree (much like a folder structure) the content of a fbx file's node hierarchy.